# Limit as $(x,y)\to (0, 0)$ of implicit function

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, implicit-function

Question:  Evaluate the following limit: $$\lim _{(x, y) \rightarrow(0,0)} \left(\frac{y^2}{x^4+y^2}=0.6\right)$$

I don't really know how to handle the fact that this is an implicit function and not the function $f(x,y) = \frac{y^2}{x^4+y^2}$.  I'm guessing that you can show that the limit does not exist by showing that the limit along two different paths are different, but not quite sure.

Path 1: $x^2 = y$
\begin{align*}
    \lim _{\underset{\text{Along path } x^2 = y}{{(x, y) \rightarrow(0,0)}}}  \frac{y^2}{x^4+y^2}=0.6 &\Leftrightarrow \lim _{y \rightarrow 0} \frac{y^2}{y^2+y^2}=0.6\\
                                                                                                      &\Leftrightarrow  \lim _{y \rightarrow 0} \frac{y^2}{2y^2}=0.6\\
                                                                                                      &\Leftrightarrow \lim _{y \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{2}=0.6\\
                                                                                                      &\Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{2} = 0.6.
  \end{align*}

Path 2: $x = 0$
\begin{align*}
\lim _{\underset{\text{Along path } x = 0}{{(x, y) \rightarrow(0,0)}}}  \frac{y^2}{x^4+y^2}=0.6 &\Leftrightarrow \lim _{y \rightarrow 0} \frac{y^2}{0+y^2}=0.6\\
                                                                                                  &\Leftrightarrow  \lim _{y \rightarrow 0} \frac{y^2}{y^2}=0.6\\
                                                                                                  &\Leftrightarrow \lim _{y \rightarrow 0} 1=0.6                                                                                               
  \end{align*}
It seems that something doesn't quite make sense as I end up with two numbers that are not $0.6$ equal to $0.6$.  I was really confused how to proceed, but this is my best effort attempt.

Comment: If there is an implicit function involved you should tell us *which implicit function there is!* Sounds like $y$ and $x$ are tied together by some equation and it is kinda crucial to know which equation!

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Sorry.  The implicit function is y^2/(x^4 + y^2) = 0.6.  I have added parentheses to make that connection more explicit.

Comment: Ok, so you are approaching the origin along the curve  $y^2=0.6 (x^4+y^2)$. But what function are you taking the limit of? Can't really be $y^2/(x^4+y^2)$ because that became now a constant (even though the origin is a singular point of the curve). Or rather, the limit of that function is now trivially $0.6$ because the limit of a constant function is that constant.

Comment: The curve from the implicit equation is the union of two parabolas thru the origin, one being the mirror image of the other. Can you give more background? What is the exact assignment? Or if this is not an exercise, the exact passage from a text, where you saw this. That might help us sort this out.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen So, unfortunately the entire question is as written.  It is a question from one of the class exercises (not graded).  Looking at the TA's solution, he just shows that the limit of f(x,y) = (y^2)/(x^4 + y^2) DNE using two paths and ignores the = 0.6 part of the equation.  But I was just really curious/confused with the addition of = 0.6.  What you say makes a lot of sense that "The limit of that function is now trivially 0.6 because the limit of a constant function is that constant".  Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have found that the limit along two different paths is different, this means that the initial limit does not exist. Another simple path to choose is the path $y = 0$ which yields $0$ as a limit which again gives a different result.